# Writing the wave equation in different ways

Tags: waves, conventions

If the wave expression is of the form $A \sin(\omega t - kx + \varphi_0)$, can it also be of the form $A \sin(kx -\omega t + \varphi_0)$ ?

Comment: That is an expression, not an equation; both expressions describe similar waves, with the only difference between them a phase shift

Comment: In this case, what is the difference of phase shifts?

Comment: The second expression can be written as $\sin(kx - \omega t + \phi_0) = -\sin(-kx + \omega t - \phi_0) = \sin(-kx + \omega t+ [\pi - \phi_0])$.
From this you may see that the phase difference between the first and second expression is $\phi_0 - [\pi - \phi_0] = 2\phi_0 - \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these two equations is that they're "inverse" from each other. They basically follow a `sin(x)` function and a `sin(-x)` function. In other words these equations are separated by a phase factor of `pi/2`. Basically they can be valid solutions of the wave equations depending how you define your variables and your origin.

Comment: Take note that this is the plane wave equation and is usually used as an approximation  of how explain most waves found in nature.